# Image getting cropped of

Tags: css, image, crop

I have an image that gets cropped when I set the background size to cover but it is not wide enough if i change the background size to contain. I have specific width and height I just can't seem to find a solution for it to not get cropped.

```
.hard-case-container {
background-image: url(/images/HARDCASE.png);
height: 536px;
width: 648px;
border-radius: 25px;
background-size: cover;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-around;
```

Comment: background-size: 100% 100%; ?

Comment: [https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Comment: Different devices, and indeed different windows on desktops, have different aspect ratios. You can never get an image to fit exactly all possibilities unless you don't mind the image being stretched in one direction or the other. It's not just a question of landscape versus portrait. It's a good idea to pick an image that has a good central portion and show as much of that as you can on each viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're missing a closing bracket in your CSS.

Secondly, if you have a landscape image you want to fit in your potrait screen, then this will not work. Same goes for the other way around.

You will always have to find a compromise - either cut some part of the image or let some part of the image be white (or another background color set).

If you force your image to fit the screen, it will look drawn out.